# JavaScript Page Not Redirecting Properly

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I'm trying to create  a page system for `user_profile.html` using a parameter from the URL and accessing using JavaScript.

However, for some reason my page does not refresh using the `#` parameter. I'm not sure why this is happening. I've put my redirection function and the output below.

**Code:**

```
function pageRedirect(page) {
    var url = window.location.href.replace('#'+window.location.hash.substr(1), '#'+page);
    console.log("@@@@");
    console.log(url);
    console.log("@@@@");
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

**Chrome console output:**

`@@@@
user_profile.js:296 http://**********/user_profile.html#1
user_profile.js:297 @@@@
Navigated to http://**********/user_profile.html`

**Even though the URL gets changed to the same thing with a `#1` at the end it does not get refreshed with that parameter.**

Comment: Changing the location hash won't cause a page refresh. This is on purpose. You can spy the `onhashchange` event and reload the page manually, though

Comment: So what's the solution?

Comment: after changing the location, try `window.location.reload()`

Comment: I tried what you said Sucker, but it produces the same result.

Comment: Use location.href with the correct url: `location.href = url` append a random value to avoid caching.

Comment: Still doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to change the hash of an url will be :

```
window.location.hash = page; // not the URL, just the '#something' part without the '#'
```

And if you need to reload the page after this, you can do this :

```
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: Hmm. Using this produces the same issue: `var url = window.location.href.replace('#'+window.location.hash.substr(1), '#'+page);
 window.location.hash = url;
 window.location.reload();`